# What is this unusual butterfly?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Sighted in West London, July 23rd., 2022. The weather was cool and overcast. I could only get a picture of the underwing, but the upper wing was orange towards the head, and white towards the tail, with a black eyespot in the orange section

[image: Sighted in West London, July 23rd., 2022.].

I have tried a Google image search, but I am not finding any results among common UK or European species. The Orange Tip is not a world away, but the underwing is quite different. Could this be a rare visitor? Size, perhaps 4 cm from head to tail.

Answer (score 2):

It's a moth, specifically a Jersey Tiger Moth - can be seen in parts of the UK, more usually the south west, though it seems to be spreading more within the UK. Info here https://butterfly-conservation.org/moths/jersey-tiger

Comment: This is clearly correct, but answers are most useful (and to get a better response) if you *explain* why your identification is correct. Specifically, please [edit] your answer to add discussion of key features that led you to this conclusion and supporting references or at least validated images. Without this your answer is indistinguishable from opinion and less useful to other users. Posts are expected to be self-sufficient — i.e. not require leaving this site. ——— You may wish to take the [tour] and consult the [help] pages for additional advice on [Answer] effectively on this site.